# How to show webview in asynctask of android?

Tags: android, twitter, webview, android-asynctask

I wanted to show a webview in asynctask in android.I am trying authorize my twitter application.But,when I click on Login button it redirects me to the browser.So, I want to show a webview on my activity.I wrote following code but my application gets crashed.
So, how can I achieve this ?

my code for login into twitter account -

```
private class TwitterLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

          @Override
          protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Check if already logged in
            if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
                ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
                builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
                Configuration configuration = builder.build();

                TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
                twitter = factory.getInstance();

                try {
                    requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
                    wv.loadUrl(requestToken.getAuthorizationURL());
                    setContentView(wv);

                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                    wv.loadUrl(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL());
                    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        //redirects to browser      
        //MainActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));

                } catch (TwitterException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            if (isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
                // User already logged into twitter
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Already Logged into Twitter",         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the results of the login to the `onPostExecute` method of the asyncTask, and execute the webview changes there. But just to be sure, please post a stacktrace.

Comment: Didn't you notice the `setContentView(wv);` in `doInBackground()`? First and foremost that is the problem.

Comment: I set wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                    wv.loadUrl(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL());
                    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);setContentView(wv); in postExecute and removed setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); now its working fine. but after click on "Authorize App" button in webview it gives error as "token null is not for an application" what does that means...?

Comment: @user3851588 Have you read my answer? You must not call `setContentView()` outside of `onCreate()` you are just messing up your `Activity` that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can only call `setContentView(...);` once in `onCreate()` what you are trying to do isn't possible. The `WebView` has to:

- Be part of the original layout. You can set its visibility to gone initally and then show it when you need it
- Or you can create the `WebView` programmatically and add it to the view hierarchy as soon as you need it.
- Or you can create a new `Activity` which only contains a `WebView` and pass the url to the new `Activity` when you want to display the website.

The first and third option are the preferable ones.